# Do second-order linear ODEs always have singularities at infinity?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, singularity

My textbook says Laguerre's Equation $ xy''+(1-x)y'+ay =0 $ has singularities at $ x=0$ and $x=\infty. $

However, rearranging the equation gives $ y''+\frac{(1-x)}{x}y'+\frac{a}{x}y =0 $, and neither $ \frac{(1-x)}{x} $ nor $ \frac{a}{x} $ diverge at  $ x = \infty $.

Do we just assume it diverges at $ x=\infty $? Or is it to do with dividing by $x$?

Comment: $\exp(\sqrt x)$ is singular at infinity, even if it is a nice regular function on the positive half-axis. Explore what happens if you set $y(x)=v(u)$, $u=1/x$.